# Query MVC {search parameters}

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have this Service "Search"

```
public IEnumerable<PainelChamada> Search(PainelChamadaParamenters parameters)
{
  var query = base.context.PaineisChamada.AsQueryable();
  if (parameters.Id.HasValue)
    query = query.Where(x => x.Id == parameters.Id);
  if (parameters.DataAcessoInicio.HasValue)
    query = query.Where(x => x.DataModificacao == parameters.DataAcessoInicio);
  if (parameters.DataAcessoFim.HasValue)
    query = query.Where(x => x.DataModificacao == parameters.DataAcessoFim);
  if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(parameters.Descricao))
    query = query.Where(x => x.Descricao.Contains(parameters.Descricao));
  return query;
}
```

I need insert "Fornecedores" inside Service, but "Fornecedores" are list.

```
public string[] Fornecedores { get; set; }
```

How to do this?

I tried, but no success...

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to add that as another property of your Parameters object, PainelChamadaParamenters, and then in your Search function you could use it as follows assuming this is what your data model looks like:

```
 public IEnumerable<PainelChamada> Search(PainelChamadaParamenters parameters)
 {
     var query = base.context.PaineisChamada.AsQueryable();
     if (parameters.Id.HasValue)
         query = query.Where(x => x.Id == parameters.Id);
     if (parameters.DataAcessoInicio.HasValue)
         query = query.Where(x => x.DataModificacao == parameters.DataAcessoInicio);
     if (parameters.DataAcessoFim.HasValue)
         query = query.Where(x => x.DataModificacao == parameters.DataAcessoFim);
     if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(parameters.Descricao))
         query = query.Where(x => x.Descricao.Contains(parameters.Descricao));

     if (parameters.Fornecedores.Length > 0)
         query = query.Where(x => parameters.Fornecedores.ToList().Contains(x.Fornecedor));

     return query;
    }
```

Comment: 2 errors. Error 2 Instance argument: cannot convert from 'string[]' to 'System.Linq.IQueryable<System.Collections.Generic.ICollection<IBM.FiatGroup.EJIS.Models.PainelChamadaFornecedor>>' C:\ProjetosRTC\W132\03 - implementacao\aplicativo\web\Services\PainelChamadaServices.cs 75 42 Services

Comment: Error 3 'string[]' does not contain a definition for 'Contains' and the best extension method overload 'System.Linq.Queryable.Contains<TSource>(System.Linq.IQueryable<TSource>, TSource)' has some invalid arguments C:\ProjetosRTC\W132\03 - implementacao\aplicativo\web\Services\PainelChamadaServices.cs 75 42 Services

Comment: try calling the .ToList() extension method on the Fornecedores array.  Updated code sample.